# Rewriting a project in a different language, Git convention?

Tags: git, github, programming-languages

Last year I wrote a university project on Python 2.7, in the year since then I've learned Java and I wish to rewrite this project in Java.

I have a GitHub repo for the Python version, and wish to have one for the Java version.

Is the standard procedure to create a whole new repo called something like "`NAME-Java`", to fork the original Python one, or to branch it? I have no intention of ever merging these in the future.

I had a search, but couldn't find search terms that led me to a useful source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the standard procedure to create a wholr new repo called something like "NAME-Java",

A new repo makes sense. Its naming convention is left to your initiative.

- Branching would be relevant if you benefit from merges.
- Forking would be relevant if you benefit from pull requests.

Comment: Is there any way to formally link the new repo with the old one, other than just a hypertext link in the readme?

Comment: @IsaacJordan no formal way. Even the fork is specific to GitHub or BitBucket (repo hosting services), and not to Git itself.

Comment: @IsaacJordan on second thought, you could reference the original repo in the second repo as [**a submodule**](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules): this is a lightweight reference ([a gitlink entry](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309) in the index)